# How can I hide phone number during incoming call and display only contact name?

Tags: contacts, calls, privacy

I wish to show only contact name during incoming call, for some privacy reasons I wish to hide numbers and display only contact name.

I won't usually pick up anonymous calls, is there any option to achieve this?

Android version 4.4 and without root option is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using [Lollipop Call Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluepea.lollipopcall) which shows only the Contact name and its same as the Lollipop style calling screen and theme which you can customize the way to want to.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no out-of-the-box way to achieve this. Maybe knowing the device that you're using will help (by editing your question, or commenting on it), but I doubt that.

That being said, You can achieve your goal with an app, like [Full Screen Caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androminigsm.fscifree). In there, at `Settings->Display` there are check boxes for `Display phone number` and `Display name`.

Personally, I wasn't too impressed with this app, but it does what you wanted.